# Proof of Cayley Bacharach Theorem That Doesn't Refer to "Independent Conditions"

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Could anyone direct me to a proof of the Cayley Bacharach theorem that doesn't use "independent conditions" in place of Hilbert functions? I am trying to prove it algebraically and I am having trouble using that phrase in a way that makes sense to me and seems rigorous. Essentially, where I can find an algebraic proof of Cayley Bacharach that uses Hilbert functions?

Comment: What exactly do you want? Something that laboriously computes the Hilbert function for a configuration of 8 points lying at the intersection of two cubics and compares to the full 9 points? And can you tell us what standard sources you *don't* like? Incidentally, the term "independent conditions" refers to the fact that subspaces of a fixed vector space (in this case sub spaces of the form $V_p \subset k[x,y,z]_3$ where $V_p$ is all the cubics vanishing at $p$) can intersect in a "minimal" way (i.e. if the subspaces are chosen at random)...

Comment: ...or so that the rank of the intersection is higher than necessary. It is in the former case that we say the points in question "impose independent conditions on cubics."